# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

Now that your community has entered into design independent graduation, I can co-opt this existing thread and turn it into an official Community Ads thread. Please note that there have been some changes to the requirements for ads.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. <s>In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.</s> *Functionality is not actually enabled yet.*

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **40 KB**
- If the ad has a white background, it *must* have at least a 1x1 border of non-white

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](/ads/display/5743).

Comment: No, this post does not mean that a new site design is ready. I'm just being proactive ([optimistic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/148099) (delusional)).

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with thinking about community ads right now, but we're not quite ready to turn them on just yet... it's going to be another 6-8 weeks, while we work on rolling out [design-independent graduation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) to Code Review and the rest of the network.

Comment: I know it's technically advertising for the competition, but perhaps someone wants to create an ad for http://exercism.io/ ?

Comment: @Pops are we there yet? ;-)

Comment: About the size limit.... there's this on Meta.SE that is applied to these ads, right? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6539/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 18):

[image: Reviewing VBA? Rubberduck VBE Addin]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Active bounties]

Comment: Interesting. I don't suppose it's an actual count, is it?

Comment: @RubberDuck [yes, it is](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) :-)

Comment: This would be cool, but we would need to get Stack Exchange to allow JavaScript or something like that, rather than a static image... has someone inquired about that?

Comment: @Phrancis, not really. Remember SimonForsberg's GitHub badge project? Similar to that.

Comment: @Phrancis I have seen this on several sites now.  It does work.

Comment: @Phrancis the trick is that it is not a static image. The image is generated dynamically by a back-end. Then the back-end sends image-data to the clients asking for the image. That's how both this and my [GitHub Review Shield](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95459/31562) works.

Comment: The link doesn't seem display the same image any more :o

Comment: @jacwah There are no open bounties at the moment!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Cardshifter online card game]

Answer (score 9):

[image: importBlogKit.com]

Comment: I am not convinced that Code Review should promote or condone the eating of elephants.

Comment: For what it's worth, importBlogKit does not either.  It simply provides instructions for doing so, if one feels so inclined.

Comment: I am not convinced that Code Review should promote, or condone: *"If you’re telling a programmer that a particular piece of source code does not work, then you should no longer consider yourself a programmer."* or *"When programmers come to me and simply say “this code does not work,” I send them away.  Their problem is not solvable by me or anyone."* -> http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: Despite it being 100% in-line with the network's "Unclear what you're asking" close reason.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Use JSFiddle's TidyUp to clean up your JS!]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Brainduck - Difficult languages need powerful IDEs]