# What kind of community ads do we encourage as a community?

Tags: discussion

[Community ads](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/community-promotion-ads-2015) will eventually be enabled on this site (6-8 weeks I wager).

The system works by community voting. Anyone from anywhere can come to our meta and post an ad for anything - it's our job to vote it up or down and decide if we want to see that ad displayed on our main site.

What kind of ads would we want to promote?

What kind of ads would we *not* want to see?

Why?

Comment: Don't we, as a community, vote on the ads already? I don't understand this thread. The community can judge the ads on an individual basis and vote on whether or not they want to see it.

Comment: @nhgrif We do that too. But there has been a bit of discussion in chat recently, as you are aware of, about the current ads. This meta question is a way of figuring that out, and I personally hope this meta will additionally be a way of coming up with ideas for other ads.

Answer (score 10):

> anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

- If it leads the community to giving good reviews of code, then let's see it.
- If it is something that the community is active in, let's see it.

  - Community Challenges
  - Community Projects
  - Community Events

#### Community Projects

These are things like

- [RubberDuck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/) is a project put on by a couple of Code Reviewers and is open to improvement by anyone, lots of the code for this project has been posted on CR for Review.

  - *It would be nice for the site to have a link to CR or to the [chat room for the project](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking)*
- [Memer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96724/the-2nd-monitor-chatroom-translator) is another project that was recently started on CR by one of our very own JavaScript reviewers

These are just a couple of the projects that the Community is working on.

Comment: *Biased*, but Rubberduck is also a static code analysis/refactoring tool, so that also makes it relevant for the site. I do think there's a link to the chatroom in the [tag:rubberduck] wiki too.

Comment: it's in the GitHub readme file

Comment: We certainly need an ad about the community challenges, but I lack the photoshop skills for that... Voluntaries?

Comment: I haven't been finding time while I am at home for this either.  I have some Photoshop skills.

Answer (score 10):

Community ads are an extension of the site. They are probably the most colorful and visible component on a site's home page (if/when you see them).

Community ads were created to allow "people" to advertise on Stack Exchange without paying money to do so, on the condition that the ads and their backing information are things the community would "want". On Stack Overflow the ads are restricted to open source projects, and have other restrictions too. On other sites the threshold is more relaxed. [The underlying premise still stands](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/), though:

> *The goal is to help visitors find out about the cool stuff your community is doing and help promote activities they find important. And it's all visible right there on the sidebar next to every question, and the homepage.*

Community ads are there because they are what the community "endorses". It says: *"We are Code Review, and we think this is good: **LinkToABC**"* It should be drawing visibility to things the "Community" is doing, not isolated individuals. It should be promoting activities that would be important to the general community.

So, there is nothing inherently wrong with any ad posted to the ad-vetting post: [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/community-promotion-ads-2015) (as long as it is not rude, offensive, etc.)

Remember, if an ad is not conformant with the goals of the Community Ads, then vote it down. If it is conformant, and it also is something you want the site to promote, then vote it up. If you are uncertain, or ambivalent, then leave it alone.

(*Reminder:* Community ads should .... *help visitors find out about the cool stuff your community is doing and help promote activities they find important* )

**"Community Ads" means "advertising the community", not "things to advertise on the site".**